# Regular Expression to match lines not starting with [ and not ending with ] (ini headers)

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, ini

I'm trying to write a where clause in Powershell using a regular expression that will only match lines (items in an array) that do not begin with [ AND do not end with ] (ini headers).

```
$test = @('test', '[test]', '[te]st', 'te[st]')
```

The below is as far as I could get. It matches only 'test'.

```
$test | where-object {$_ -match '^(?!\[).+(?<!\])$'}
```

'test', '[te]st' and 'te[st]' should be matched. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

In `[te]st`, the initial negative lookahead fails.

In `te[st]`, the final negative lookbehind fails.

---

**Solution**

We need to use the alternator `|` to make sure either one or the other scenario is valid..if both lookarounds fail, then we won't get a match:

```
^         (?# match the beginning of the string)
(?:       (?# start non-capturing group)
  (?!\[)  (?# negative lookahead for [)
  .+      (?# match 1+ characters)
 |        (?# OR)
  .+      (?# match 1+ characters)
  (?<!\]) (?# negative lookbehind for ])
)         (?# end non-capturing group)
$         (?# match the end of the string)
```

[*Demo*](http://regex101.com/r/hJ4gB5)

---

**Note:** I put the alternation into a non-capturing group so that I do not need to include the anchors `^` and `$` around each possible statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that by utilizing the regex ^ and $ anchors and avoid the lookarounds.
Lookaround operations are less efficient than direct matches, and should be avoided if a direct match solution will work.

```
$test = @('test', '[test]', '[te]st', 'te[st]')
$test -notmatch '^\s*\[.+\]\s*$'

test
[te]st
te[st]
```

The \s* on either end will account for any leading or trailing spaces in the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you look for patterns that do start with [ and end with ] and just check that the word doesnt match the regex? That would make the regex much easier:

`\[[^\]]*\]`